# Thunderbird and SoGo connector: Never asked for credentials

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon, owncloud, carddav

I'm trying to access my owncloud address book using Thunderbird and the SoGo connector under Windows.

Under Linux I have no issues whatsoever - it works perfectly.
Under Windows however I'm never being prompted for any credentials after I added a new remote address book and I'm therefore unable to retrieve my address book.
I tried deleting and recreating the address book several times, restarting Thunderbird and Windows itself, but I never got a credentials prompt.
I checked the 'saved passwords' section in the Thunderbird settings to ensure that no wrong credentials are stored (because SoGo fails silently if the credentials are incorrect).
The owncloud address book URL is correct as well.

I'm using Thunderbird 31.1.1 and SoGo 24.0.6

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I resolved it myself by downgrading to SoGo Connector 10.0.6.

Comment: This continues to be a problem.  Using Thunderbird 38.5.1 and attempting to us SoGo Connector I had the same issue.  I downloaded the older versions of Sogo Connector from [here](http://sogo.nu/files/downloads/SOGo/Thunderbird/).  10.0.6 finally worked.
Unfortunately version 10.0.6 does not save user/pass, which makes it almost unusable.

Comment: **Update:** Now works using latest version (31.0.2) of SoGo Connector.  As soon as Thunderbird's Lightening extension was installed, everything worked as expected.  Looks like it is required even for address book.

Comment: Good that you was able to solve it on your own. I have written a detailed tutorial on this. Maybe you might wanna have a look on it: http://www.kwoxer.de/2016/05/05/owncloud-mit-thunderbird-und-android-verbinden-komplettanleitung/#Thunderbird_Contacts_Birthday

Answer (score 0):

After you installed the addon, restarted thunderbird and entered the uri to you owncloud addressbook, restart thunderbird again. SoGo Connector should then ask for the credentials.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't

Answer (score 0):

SoGo Connector never asks for CardDAV credentials in Thunderbird 38 under Windows, probably a bug in TB, Lightning or SoGo.

Resolved by downgrading to Thunderbird 31, there everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by first removing the SOGo Connector and then installing the [Saved Password Manager Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/saved-password-editor/) for Thunderbird and created a new username / password of type annotations (or similar..). Afterwards I reinstalled the SOGo Connector and it worked right away. I found the solution on this [german Webmail-Site](https://posteo.de/hilfe/wie-richte-ich-den-adressbuchabgleich-mit-thunderbird-ein). The proposed way of installing the Saved Password Manager afterwards didn't work. They suggest this workaround if you get asked for the password everytime, I wasn't asked a single time.